# Lots of errors when I try to connect to a database using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this problem. I am trying to connect to a database and push a text user. When I open the file I just get lots of errors. You can see the errors and my code further down. FYI: my database is in MySQLi

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: hostname nor servname provided, or not known in
>   /www/webvol9/rj/fxgnq6r66hz6x2j/*my
>   domain*/public_html/action_page.php on line 3
>
> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002):
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: hostname nor servname
>   provided, or not known in /www/webvol9/rj/fxgnq6r66hz6x2j/*my
>   domain*/public_html/action_page.php on line 3
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: query in
>   /www/webvol9/rj/fxgnq6r66hz6x2j/*my
>   domain*/public_html/action_page.php on line 7
>
> Warning: mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   /www/webvol9/rj/fxgnq6r66hz6x2j/*my
>   domain*/public_html/action_page.php on line 7
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on
>   null in /www/webvol9/rj/fxgnq6r66hz6x2j/*my
>   domain*/public_html/action_page.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /www/webvol9/rj/fxgnq6r66hz6x2j/*my
>   domain*/public_html/action_page.php on line 8

```
<?php
// Create connection
$mysqli = new mysqli("https://mysql687.loopia.se", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "People");

$query = "INSERT INTO 'People' ('Name', 'Password', 'Username') VALUES ('Emil', 'hejhej', 'emil')";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

$mysqli->close();
$stmt->close();
?>
```

Comment: write `$query` instead of `$querry`

Comment: use this syntax `mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');`

Comment: Remove **https** from your host address and fixed a typo in your `$query` variable name. Write `$query` instead of `$querry`

Comment: Don't include real conneciton strings or keys in your code. Stack Overflow is public!

Answer (score 0):

First connect with proper credentials to your database. Don't quote table name and column names in

```
$query = "INSERT INTO People (Name, Password, Username) VALUES ('Emil', 'hejhej', 'emil')";
```

`$stmt->close();` should come before `$mysqli->close();`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a **lot** of bugs here

> **Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: hostname nor servname provided, or not known in ...**
>
> **Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002):
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: hostname nor servname
>   provided, or not known in ...**

Are because you connect with the database through port 443 when you put https:// in front of the domain.

Just did a port scanner and port 443 is closed, the default mySQL port 3306 is open so just enter `mysql687.loopia.se` without the `https://`

[image: port 3306]
[image: port 443]

> **Notice: Undefined variable: query in ...**

Replace single quotes for table columns to backticks or none:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `People` (`Name`, `Password`, `Username`) VALUES ('Emil', 'hejhej', 'emil')";
```

Also close statement before database connection (also only close the database connection when its the end of the script. Not every time you run a query).

```
$stmt = null;
$mysqli = null;
```